# How to return an array of properties that match pattern using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, underscore.js, lodash

Is there any way using the `lodash` function to return an array of properties that match to a pattern?

```
_.magicMethod({a:'hi', b:13, c:undefined, d:null, e:null}, null)

return => `['d','e']`
```

I checked the docs but I don't found nothing :/
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably not a single function version of it; but you can do:

```
function magicMethod(obj, value) {
    return _.keys(_.pick(obj, function(propertyValue) {
         return propertyValue === value;
    }));
}
```

`_.pick` creates an object with only the properties with values matching the specified value, then `_.keys` extracts the keys of that object.